Model OneToMany relation with "two parents" (entity and view) with JPA and Hibernate
Given the following classic OneToMany relationship between a blog post and its comments:
// parent entity
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
}

// child entity
@Entity
@Table(name = "post_comment")
public class PostComment {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id", referencedColumnName = "post_id")
    private Post post;
}

Now, our database provides an additional view joining several other tables. Let's call it view_post. The list of post comments should be part of this view as modeled below:
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "view_post")
public class PostView {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    // other fields omitted...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    private List<PostComment> comments;
}

This however doesn't work as clearly indicated by the exception:
Association 'ViewPost.comments' is 'mappedBy' a property named 'post' which references the wrong entity type 'Post', expected 'ViewPost'

I cannot find a way to model the entity representing the view. What I could do is to add another relation to Post and link ViewPost to it, but isn't there a simpler solution?
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "postView")
private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();


well, PostComment.post is of Type Post and not of type PostView. Also, if you had for one Post id both instances loaded: Post and PostView. And you added a comment to Post.comments, then it would be ambiguous what JPA should do with PostView.comments.
My suggestion is to change the OneToMany in PostView to
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "view_post")
public class PostView {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    // other fields omitted...

    @OneToMany(updateable=false, insertable=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="post_id")
    private List<PostComment> comments;
}

Disclaimer: I didn't try it. It's just typing out of my head. Not sure you if you need the "updateable=false, insertable=false" but maybe.
